# distribution of a self-exciting counting process at time n

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains

We look at a time-inhomogeneous counting process $X_{n}$ that evolves according to the following transition probabilities: $$ \begin{alignat}{2}P(X_{n+1}&=k+1|X_{n}=k) &=\frac{f(k)}{n+1}\\ P(X_{n+1}&=k|X_{n}=k)&=   1-\frac{f(k)}{n+1}\end{alignat} $$ where $f$ is a (sub)linear function and $X_{1}=0$.

I now need bounds on the expression $|P(X_{n+1}\geq k)-P(X_{i}\geq k)|$. Does anyone have an idea how to approach this problem?

Thanks very much!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to estimate? What is $ i $?

Comment: The overall goal is to get a rate of convergence of $X_n$ with the help of Stein's method. During the calculations the stated term appears, where $X_i$ denotes the state the Markov chain is in at time $i$.